# Non-looping way in Numpy to convert a string of letters into a boolean array (corresponding to each letter of the string)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, numpy

I have an array of strings, and I'd like to take those strings and treat them each as boolean arrays corresponding to the alphabet (A-Z).

My goal is to do this in vectorized way and avoid any looping.

E.g.

```
Input:
A = np.array(['A'])
B = np.array(['AB'])
C = np.array(['AZ'])
D = np.array(['AZ','BAZ'])


Output:
A = np.array([1,0,0,0,...0]) 
B = np.array([1,1,0,0,...0])
C = np.array([1,0,0,0,...1])
D = np.array([[1,0,0,0,...1], [1,1,0,0,...1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `map` with [`MultiLabelBinarizer.transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)

We can `fit` the `MultiLabelBinarizer` on the capital letters from `A-Z`, then transform the arrays A, B, C, and D using the transform method of `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
import string
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit([*string.ascii_uppercase])
A, B, C, D = map(mlb.transform, (A, B, C, D))
```

---

```
>>> A
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> B
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0]])
```